# Почему при обращении к методам класса через точку VS показывает в том числе и private методы унаследованного класса?

Tags: visual-studio

Есть три класса. Каждый наследует другой с модификатором наследования private. Соответственно компилятор выдаёт ошибку при обращении верхнего в наследовании объекта класса к public методу move() класса родителя, но при этом этот метод видимый при обращении к нему через точку. Как сделать так чтобы VS не предлагал его в качестве доступного метода?

One.cpp:

```
class One
{
public:
    void move()
    {

    }
};
```

Two.cpp:

```
class Two: private One
{
};
```

Three.cpp:

```
class Three: private Two
{
};
```

main.cpp:

```
main()
{
    Three three;
    
    three.move();  // ошибка: нет доступа к "One::move" 
}
```

Метод не должен быть видимым:

[image]

Comment: вопрос не связан с программированием и метка с++ тут явно лишняя

Comment: а покажите ваши .h файлы и что подключено в main.cpp?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо у вас в настройках IntelliSense отключена фильтрация по уровню доступа. Ее можно включить в Options → Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced → IntelliSense → Member List Filter Inaccessible.

Comment: Member List Filter Inaccessible был включён

Comment: @Сергей Тогда проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: что значит не воспроизводится?

Comment: @Сергей Это значит, что у меня при выключенной опции в примере из вопроса `move` показывается в списке предложений, а при включенной - нет.

Comment: Эта опция скрывает только то, что находится в private и protected секциях